# jQuery - Having the same HTML twice renders my script inoperative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-effects

I'm quite new to jQuery and I have come up with script which affects the HTML below. The script works perfectly and I have gotten it to whether I would like. The problem I am having
is when I'm duplicating the HTML and the script, once clicked, only shows the last project-info and project-images within the document. I've tried quite a few different methods just as

`$(this).children()`

but I can't seem to get any to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.apple').click(function() {
     $('#darken').addClass('dark');
     $('.project-info').delay('1000').slideDown('slow');  
     $('.project-images').delay('1000').fadeIn('slow');
   });
 });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close').click(function() {
        $(".project-info, .project-images").fadeOut('slow');
    });
  });
```

HTML

```
    <div class="apple">
      <img src="http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/apple-logo.jpg"/>
    </div>

        <div class="project-info" style="display:none;">
          <div class="project-title">
            <h1>hello world</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="details">
            <p>dkusdufhu suskueh sukh suefhuksdfnkuesnfukneukf nseuknfukenfuk nukefnuksn fukfuksukfnuksenf unseukfunfukfunufen u u u ef euhfuehfeufu g gfd gerjkg rjgrjg j js grg rgsg dkusdufhu suskueh sukh</p>

          <div class="links">
            <a href="#">link</a>
          </div>

          <div class="close"></div>
        </div><!-- end of project info -->



      </div>
      <div class="project-images" style="display:none;">
      <div class="-images">
        <img src="http://cdn4.spiegel.de/images/image-499233-galleryV9-grcy.jpg" />
        <img src="http://cdn4.spiegel.de/images/image-499233-galleryV9-grcy.jpg" />
      </div>

      <div class="close end"></div>
    </div> <!-- Project Images -->

  </div> <!-- # Darken -- >
```

Comment: may be you are using #Darken in ID selector, and it is duplicated when you duplicate the html...

Comment: " when I'm duplicating the HTML and the script" - where is the code that does that..? where is `#darken`? is it being duplicated too? can you provide a minimal demo?

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here. I've loaded your code into this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q9Aa8/ and it shows the apple logo. What do you mean by 'duplicating the HTML and the script'?

Comment: @Chrishodges copy pasted the HTML/script

Comment: sorry about that. What I'm planning to do is create a portfolio with only images. Once the image has been clicked, the divs will appear to show the details. I have updated your jsfiddle Chris to show my incorrect results. http://jsfiddle.net/q9Aa8/2/ What is happening is when you click on either the apple or the boat, all details are shown. I only want the details that belong to the individual image to show. thats why I wanted to use the $(this)

Comment: @Wiseguy - Ok, I understand now. It might be worth editing your original question so that the info and jsFiddle in your above comment is in the main question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. Children wouldn't work in the above example because the divs with class 'apple' don't have any children. You need to move that first closing  tag to the bottom of the portfolio item so that your html for each portfolio item is structured like this:

```
<!--PORTFOLIO ITEM-->
<div class="apple">
    <!-- ICON GOES HERE-->
    <img src="http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/apple-logo.jpg"/>

    <!-- PROJECT INFO GOES HERE-->
    <div class="project-info" style="display:none;">

    </div>
    <!-- PROJECT IMAGES GOES HERE-->
    <div class="project-images" style="display:none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I.e. the divs with classes 'project-info' and 'project-images' are inside the 'apple' div. Then change this:

```
$('.project-info').delay('1000').slideDown('slow');  
$('.project-images').delay('1000').fadeIn('slow');
```

to this:

```
$(this).children('.project-info').delay('1000').slideDown('slow');  
$(this).children('.project-images',this).delay('1000').fadeIn('slow');
```

If you've updated your html correctly, `$(this)` will be pointing to a div element that does indeed have children with classes 'project-info' and 'project-images'. Here's an updated JSFiddle that should do you what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/8k3Ms/1/

Comment: Brilliant! I thought it was something like this and now i see why. There is a problem with my close script now I believe. If I open the apple and close, and then open the boat. both details open simonimatiously. Would the close script need to include $(this) or if I positioned it above the project-info & project-images I could use children again?

Comment: At the end of the close function callback you need add the line 'return false;'. If you don't then the click event will bubble up into the in the 'apple' div. I've updated the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8k3Ms/3/ and here's some more info on event bubbling: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing If you're happy with my answer it would be great if you could give it an up vote (up arrow on the left). Thanks.